# Why is Traefik not reading my traefik.toml file when running with Docker?

Tags: docker, traefik

When following the steps mentioned at the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik/), I can't seem to make Traefik read my `traefik.toml` file.

#### This works

From `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:1.3.5
    command: --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      #- ./traefik.toml:/traefik.toml

  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=whoami"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/whoami"
```

Notice that no configuration file is mounted, and all configuration is passed as arguments.

Now, if I run `docker-compose up` I see a bunch of debug statements from Traefik. If I test the application, it works (and yes, I'm running Windows 7):

```
$ curl 'http://192.168.99.100:80/whoami'
Hostname: c94bec5d0e3e
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 172.19.0.3
GET /whoami HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.99.100
User-Agent: curl/7.50.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.99.1
X-Forwarded-Host: 192.168.99.100
X-Forwarded-Proto: http
X-Forwarded-Server: b8946b1c34a1
```

#### This doesn't work

From `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: traefik:1.3.5
    #command: --docker --docker.domain=docker.localhost --logLevel=DEBUG
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml

  whoami:
    image: emilevauge/whoami
    labels:
      - "traefik.backend=whoami"
      - "traefik.frontend.rule=PathPrefix:/whoami"
```

Notice that no arguments are passed into Traefik, only the configuration file.

Now, if I run `docker-compose up`, no log statements appear whatsoever. If I test the application, I get a 404:

```
$ curl 'http://192.168.99.100:80/whoami'
404 page not found
```

Of course, without any debug statements, it's very difficult to know what's wrong.

This is my `traefik.toml` file:

```
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.localhost"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

I've tried mounting the file to `/etc/traefik/traefik.toml` and `/traefik.toml`, and it gives the same result.

I've tried running the example mentioned in the [official example](https://hub.docker.com/_/traefik/) too, with similar results.

I am running this on Windows 7, although I'm not sure if that's relevant. I can successfully mount files in other images without issue.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: May post your Traefik.toml aswell, oh should open my eyes.. sry

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is Windows.

Do you use Docker for Windows or Docker Toolbox?
If I remember correctly, with W7 you must use Docker Toolbox.

I think your file `treafik.toml` is not mount to your container.

Comment: I'm afraid you're absolutely right. And yes, I'm using Docker Toolbox.

I tried the following experiment:
`Dockerfile`:
```FROM traefik
COPY ./traefik.toml /```

... and changed my `docker-compose.yml` to use `build: .` instead of `image: ...`

And then ran `docker-compose build && docker-compose up`. And sure enough, it works!

The logs state "Using TOML configuration file //traefik.toml", so apparently there's a mount issue.

Sigh...

Comment: There appears to be a bug with Docker on Windows, where relative paths do not work: https://forums.docker.com/t/compose-relative-host-volume-mounts-do-not-work/13951
The bug seems to be fixed on Docker for Windows (Windows 10), but not on Docker Toolbox (Windows 7).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. 
You need to specify `entryPoints` section inside traefik.toml

```
# traefik.toml
debug = true
logLevel = "DEBUG"

[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"

[docker]
endpoint = "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
domain = "docker.localhost"
watch = true
exposedbydefault = false
```

And mount it:

```
volumes:
   - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
```

(of course if docker-compose.yml and traefik.toml at the same folder)